# SQL rank/dense_rank and how to query/calculate with the result

Tags: sql, rank

So I have a table where it dense_ranks my rows. 
Here is the table:

```
COL1  | COL2  | COL3  | DENSE_RANK |
```

---

```
  a   |   b   |   c   |       1    |
  a   |   s   |   r   |       1    |
  a   |   w   |   f   |       1    |
  b   |   b   |   c   |       2    |
  c   |   f   |   r   |       3    |
  c   |   q   |   d   |       3    |
```

So now I want to select any rows where the rank was only represented once, so the 2 is all alone, but not the 1 or 3. I want to select all the rows where this occurs, but how do I do that?

Some ideas:

```
  -COUNT DISTINCT (RANK())
  -COUNT RANK()
```

but neither of those are working, any ideas? please and thank you!

happy hacking

actual code:

```
SELECT events.event_type AS "event", 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY bw_user_event.pad_id) as rank 
FROM user_event 
WHERE (software_events.software_id = '8' OR software_events.software_id = '14') 
  AND (software_events.event_type = 'install')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is it? SQL Server?

Comment: Unrelated but: if `software_id` is a number you shouldn't compare it to a string value. `'8'` is a string `8` is a number. And: it is not really helpful if the columns in your SQL code do not match the columns of your (obfuscated) sample table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Dense_ranked_table as (
 -- Your select query that generates the table with dense ranks
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK
FROM Dense_ranked_table
GROUP BY DENSE_RANK
HAVING COUNT(DENSE_RANK) = 1;
```

I don't have SQL Server to test this. So please let me know whether this works or not.

Comment: This does not work because I only rank in the select statement so to use my rank that I only create in my select will not work below, I think. What do you think?

Comment: Are you saying that your dense ranks are not stored but are calculated at run-time?

Comment: Maybe, should I dense_rank not in my select statement? is it possible to do else where?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you can use WITH clause. I have edited my response. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Still not working. I am trying: `SELECT distinct pad_id, c, dr, url FROM  (SELECT url, pad_id,           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY url) AS DR,         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY url) AS C FROM user_event) CTE WHERE C > 1`  but still not sure what my result is yielding

Answer (score 0):

I would think you can add a COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY XXXXX) where XXXXX is what you include in your dense rank.

Then wrap this in a Common Table Expression and select where your new Count is = 1.

Something like this fiddler:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae774/1

Code included here as well:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
COL1 CHAR,
COL2 CHAR,
COL3 CHAR
);

INSERT INTO T
VALUES 
('a','b','c'),
('a','s','r'),
('a','w','f'),
('b','b','c'),
('c','f','r'),
('c','q','d');

WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT  COL1 ,
        COL2 ,
        COL3, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COL1) AS DR,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1) AS C
FROM dbo.T AS t

 )
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, DR
FROM CTE 
WHERE C = 1
```

Would return just the

```
b, b, c, 2
```

row from your test data.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a but what the 'C' part does.   I made my code as follows:   `SELECT distinct pad_id, c, dr, url FROM 
(SELECT url, pad_id,  
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY url) AS DR,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY url) AS C
FROM user_event) CTE
WHERE C > 1 LIMIT 100`